# Toast does not show in setOnItemClickListener in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a fragment, and inside this fragment I would like to display a Toast whenever an item in the listView is clicked, as shown below in the code.
the problem I am facing now is, when I click any item in the list the Toast never appears.

To solve this issue, I tried to use

> getActivity as context but it did not work.
>   getActivity.getApplicationContext but it did not work as well.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

**Code**:

```
this.mItemsModels.add(new ItemModel(this.mTitle, this.mContents, this.mIsChecked));
this.mListViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this.mItemsModels);
this.mListView.setAdapter(this.mListViewAdapter);
this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), " CLICKED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: `ListViewAdapter` is your custom adapter? Have you kept any onClickListener within that adapter?

Comment: would be great if you post the entire fragment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your `fragment`

```
private Context context;
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.context = context;
    }
```

Inside your `onItemClick`

```
Toast.makeText(context, " CLICKED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```